# Growth Rate Algorithms

Tags: algorithms

Which Function is growing faster as I take the Limit as $x$ approaches infinity? 
In this case I think $g(x)$ is growing faster

$f(x) = (\ln(2x))^3$

$g(x) = (\ln(3x))^2$

I have to use L'Hospitals Rule

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Note that $f(x) = (\ln(2x))^3 = (\ln x + \ln 2)^3$ and $g(x) = (\ln(3x))^2 = (\ln x + \ln 3)^2$.

Hence, $\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \dfrac{(\ln x + \ln 2)^3}{(\ln x + \ln 3)^2} = \dfrac{(1+\frac{\ln 2}{\ln x})^3(\ln x)^3}{(1+\frac{\ln 3}{\ln x})^2(\ln x)^2} = \dfrac{(1+\frac{\ln 2}{\ln x})^3\ln x}{(1+\frac{\ln 3}{\ln x})^2}$.

Can you tell what happens to this ratio as $x \to \infty$?

Comment: A lot more informative than L'Hospital's Rule!

Comment: So Im thinking if I make x=2 for example then I will end up with a bigger number in the denominator. So I think that it approaches 0 therefore f(x) is growing slower than g(x), but I'm not sure if that's the right way to approach it

Comment: We are looking at the limit as $x \to \infty$. It would help if you at least tried plugging in "big" numbers. $x = 2$ isn't really that big.

Comment: I tried with x=100000 and I got the numerator as a bigger number. so in this case is the equation = + infinity so we can say that f(x) is growing faster than g(x)

Comment: Here is a more rigorous way to notice that. As $x \to \infty$, we have $\ln x \to \infty$. So $(1+\frac{\ln 2}{\ln x})^3 \to 1$ and $(1+\frac{\ln 3}{\ln x})^2 \to 1$, while $\ln x \to \infty$. Plugging in "big" numbers is a good way to gain intuition as to what a limit is as $x \to \infty$, but as you saw, "big" is subjective and there is no way to guarantee that the number you picked is big enough.